# space-in-parens in .prettierrc

Tags: typescript, prettier

I want to have the prettier like `space-in-parens` from eslint.

From:

```
function foo(one, two, three){
```

To:

```
function foo( one, two, three ){
```

I found this thread (https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1303) from 2017 at github but i can't found the solution.

Do you have any idea about it?
There is way to create a custom rule?

Thaaanks a lot in advance